# Why does it display only the last value of the array, and not the whole?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

Why does it display only the last value of the array, and not the whole?.
When you update the value in the database, When you update the value in the database, it outputs all

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
    this.name = this.props.name; 
    this.state = {[this.name] : []}; 
} 

componentDidMount() { 
    let cardQuantity = 
    firebase.database().ref("Users").child(this.name); 

    cardQuantity.on('value',snap => { 

        snap.forEach((childSnapshot)=> { 

            let card = {text: childSnapshot.val(), id: childSnapshot.key}; 

            this.setState({[this.name] :[card].concat(this.state[this.name])}); 
        });
    }); 
} 

render(){ 

    return ( 
        this.state[this.name].map( card => <h2 key={card.id}>{card.text}</h2>) 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState()` is async so you have to use callback form of `setState` like below:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  [this.name]: [card].concat(prevState[this.name])
}));
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrq0xxq2px

It shows 2 versions based on your code:

- fixed version that is using callback form of setState and displaying the whole list
- unfixed version based on your code that is showing only the last element of an array

From the official [React's documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> If the next state depends on the previous state, we recommend using
>   the updater function form, instead...